# How to clean a money value and return it to a integer

Tags: php

Is there a good way to strip down money values from $, € , CHF and so on.

I have money values that contain money signs which I dont need, so is there a php function or something that removes these things(all of the money signs of the world)

Current values are

```
#current      -> #stripped value(what im looking for)
€ 2.66        -> 2.66
445.77 €      -> 445.77
$ 4561.44     -> 4561.44
CHF 3`009.55  -> 3`009.55
```

EDIT:

I found a regex pattern, but it will remove the ` sign to.

```
/[^0-9,.`]/
```

Comment: No, there is no dedicated function for something as specific as this. You’ll have to write one yourself. I would probably go with a regular expression, and only match the parts you want (digits, decimal point, `)

Comment: A shitty way would be you could create a function yourself which strips each character from the string, returns integers, commas and decimals and return the whatever comes back as a float.

Comment: Find a library to handle it for you, eg: https://github.com/moneyphp/money. I'd heavily recommend _not_ trying to roll your own from scratch, money gets very complicated very fast, and it's something you really don't want to get wrong.

Comment: Guessing that `2561.44` is a typo?

Comment: Depends on if your currency strings follow a format recognised by [NumberFormatter::parseCurrency](http://php.net/manual/en/numberformatter.parsecurrency.php) ...

Comment: Honestly, unless your scope is very limited, don't try and do this yourself with Regex. In the UK we prefix the monetary value with the relevant currency sign, elsewhere it's a suffix. In the UK we use a comma as a thousands seperator, elsewhere a comma is used to seperate decimals, whilst a decimal point is used to seperate thousands, elsewhere they'll use a space. How are you going to store these values, [a float maybe?](https://twitter.com/billkarwin/status/347561901460447232) Oh Christ. What about tax rates? What do you mean the Japanese don't have decimal values? .... Find a good library.

Comment: Can't you just add the backtick to that regex? /[^0-9,.\`]/

Comment: i have tried that pattern but it will remove the backtick

Comment: You want to match /([0-9,.`]+)/, because ^ at the start of a character class negates it, meaning _everything but_ those characters

Comment: Just to make things even muddier, you can also add a prefix to the currency to make it thousands or millions etc when you look at buissness reports for example. For example `100 tkr` means `100 000 kr` if you just remove the `tkr` your data is invalid.

Comment: And your question makes no sense as you want to return an integer but you want to leave `\`` in the return. That is not a valid integer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = '445.77 € ';
preg_match_all('!\d+!', $str, $value);
print_r($value[0][0].'.'.$value[0][1]);
```

Comment: That will fall over with Japanese Yen.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$test = 'CHF 3`009.55';
preg_replace('/[^0-9-.`]+/', '', $test); //return 3`009.55
```

Comment: @user759235 sure it does. It's not an integer but it's what you expect https://3v4l.org/E9XZv